# Object in array is undefined when I try to display it

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working with React jS and fetching data from pokeapi.
Here's the data structure from the api (goes to number 5) :

```
stats  
  0
    base_stat
    effort
    stat
      name
      url
  1
    base_stat
    effort
    stat
      name
      url
```

Here's my code :

```
const minHp = pokemon?.stats[0]?.base_stat * 2 + 110;
const maxHp = pokemon?.stats[0]?.base_stat * 2 + 204;

<td className='pokemon_stats_table_row_element'>
    {minHp}
</td>
<td className='pokemon_stats_table_row_element'>
    {maxHp}
</td>
```

When I load the page there is an error that says that 'pokemon.stats is undefined' and I don't understand why it doesn't works because the path is correct and existing (i'm displaying other data from the 'stats' array and it works fine.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include an example of the resulting data from that endpoint so that people don't have to visit the link to understand the question. The point of Stack Overflow is to create questions that stand the test of time and help everyone with the same question.

Comment: @Heretic I edited it. Tell me if I need to add more info

Comment: If you're using [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining), I'm assuming you expect `pokemon` to not always be defined (or the keys of the object to have some variability). Yet you don't use optional chaining when accessing the array `pokemon.stats`. Maybe try `pokemon?.stats?.[0]?.base_stat`.

Comment: Is it an array, or an object? Is it retrieved asynchronously?

Comment: There's no way we're going to be able to tell you why `pokemon.stats` is undefined. We can tell you how to program defensively so that you don't get errors when it is, but that's about it. Best you can do is be prepared when it is undefined, and use the same API-sourced object across your app so that your entire app is affected if it is undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the optional chaining `?` operator also when indexing into the `stats` object, because that property can return undefined, like this:

```
const minHp = pokemon?.stats?.[0]?.base_stat * 2 + 110;
const maxHp = pokemon?.stats?.[0]?.base_stat * 2 + 204;
```

Comment: Thx. I thought that you couldn't put something before the []

Comment: It will make `minHp` and `maxHp` as `NaN` if they are undefined...